# How to Take Screenshots /Save a web page as PDF

Tags: browser, pdf, printing, screenshot

**How to save a page as pdf or take screenshot of the entire page which has height longer than viewport**

### Provided

1. Right Click is disabled /If tried to override it .It disables the content to be screenshoted
2. Unable to print as pdf (Print disabled appears instead of content inside  print preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, try: [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl)

If Firefox: [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fireshot/)

Web App: [web-capture.net](http://web-capture.net/)

Comment: Hey bro does monitor size /screen resolution effect the screenshot ?

Comment: @SachinDivakar Yes it does

Comment: I have paid money to for some answers /they dont allow me to print have to write that down which is not practical so any upvoted and accepted it as answer

Comment: @SachinDivakar What are you talking about?

Comment: Hey missed some words in between while typing fast .So I was asking any way to   download from chegg.com

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, you can also do the following:

1. Open Developer Tools:

   1. Right Click
   2. Click Inspect Element
2. Click the gear icon on the top right of the developer tools box
3. Under Avaliable Toolbox Buttons, there is an option: *Take a fullpage screenshot*. Check it
4. There will now be a picture of a camera beside the gear icon. Click it to take the screenshot.

If right click is not allowed, you can click on the menu icon in the toolbar, then on Developer to access developer tools. If the option is not there, then press customize, and drag it there.