# How to save a webpage as PDF exactly as it looks on web browser (no need for selectable text)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, pdf, webpage

I want to save a webpage as pdf file. A lot of tools for this task change the look/format of the webpage. I'm looking for printing the webpage to PDF as is (as on web browser) without any manipulation on style or alignment, or loss of any webpage's static components.
A similar question is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1064579/how-to-convert-a-webpage-to-pdf-with-preserving-its-look-exactly-as-on-web-brow)

However, that question has an added criteria that the text must remain selectable. I don't need that. The pdf pages can be simply screenshots of the webpage.
Currently, I do this manually. I take screenshot of the entire page, then divide it into several smaller images using Paint and save each image. Finally, I convert the images into one pdf file. This is tedious for very large webpages. So, I am basically looking for a tool to automate this.

[This](https://www.techjunkie.com/download-embedded-video/) is a webpage I want to save exactly as it looks in the browser.

Comment: Just to be clear - _exactly_ as is, ads and whatnot included?

Comment: I would prefer if the ads were excluded.

Comment: Might be too simple but have you tried printing the website with ctrl+p and the changing you printer to pdf? It works on chrome and if you have add block it will not print the adds.

Comment: @dmb the problem is printing changes the look. Sometimes, the output is quite terrible like [this](https://imgur.com/a/HK4bFba)

Comment: @fac120 A couple of years ago I assembled a tool that needed to scrap a website and take SS’s as evidence but it may be a little out of scope to you as it used python3 with selenium, lxml and requests library. With all these you can save the site locally and present it the way you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Firefox addons (and possibly Chrome addons) that take full webpage screenshots and can save them to PDF.

For example:
https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/fireshot/

You can probably find more by googling something like: chrome/firefox screenshot plugin/addon PDF

Comment: I was hoping to save large webpages as multiple pages. But, this works too. Selecting as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The one solution I found is **OPERA** (right click) SaVe as PDF (will save as exactly laid out on screen).

I looked for many solutions this is the only Browser that does it right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a virtual PDF printer like pdforge

https://www.pdfforge.org/

If there is an issue with it, dozens of other companies make similar products.

Comment: I have just used online version of the tool given [here](https://tools.pdfforge.org/html-to-pdf). But, the output is very bad.

[screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/HK4bFba)

Comment: Hmm That is odd, but definitely not usable, well others ones exist.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 97.0.2 (at least in macOS) if you right-click the web page there is a screenshot function in which you can select either "Save full page" or "Save visible".

This creates a PNG file with "screenshot", the current date and time, and the title from the page (not the URL). While I would have preferred a PDF with selectable text and links in it, this is the most faithful method I have just found.

Warning regarding some **other** solutions, a browser extension required access to passwords of web sites!!! I didn't install it!

Just saving as full page was fine for some websites, but not for something like an OpenSea listing of your own NFTs. Also, I really wanted to find an alternative that did not run scripts after launching the page. Right-clicking and select Quicklook (in Finder on macOS) actually renders those pages fine, that otherwise replaces the saved content when you open it in a modern browser. Opening such a page with another browser that won't run the javascripts was also fine, but my search today had me really not wanting any scripts to run, yet the currently displayed information to be saved.